# Increment of Intel graphic memory MB on MacBook PRO

Tags: memory, gpu, macos

I had 4GB of RAM in my MacBook PRO late 2011 and the graphic memory shown from about menu was 384MB of Intel graphic, now I've upgraded to 16GB and the graphic memory shown is 512MB.

Is it possible to upgrade the Intel graphic memory in some way to 1GB? Why does the PC show more memory now?

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD graphics are [*integrated* graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Integrated_graphics_solutions), meaning (among other things) they share the same memory as the CPU–they don't have dedicated VRAM. You can read more about it on the Apple side [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349) Under OS X, there is no (reasonable) way to adjust this besides adding more RAM.